# How to fetch data from a website without using API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, microservices

I am trying to build a REST API project with spring boot which is getting the available currencies and USD-FX exchange rates and etc. But the problem is that the currency exchange rate-related websites just provide an API only for the Exchange currency rate or the ones with more options don't give it for free. So there is a website that does not provide an API but it presents the data with time series. So is there any way to use time series instead of API in the project?

Comment: Have you tried html parsers like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or [HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/)?

Comment: @Eritrean Not yet, but I wonder if it is possible to use the time-series data from a website as API?

Comment: Without knowing about which site you are talking and how the data you desire is presented on that site, hard to tell.

Comment: This is the website I'm trying to get the currency exchange rates ==> https://www.bundesbank.de/dynamic/action/en/statistics/time-series-databases/time-series-databases/759784/759784?statisticType=BBK_ITS&listId=www_sdks_b01012_3&treeAnchor=WECHSELKURSE

Comment: They have a well documented REST-API interface!! You can find the web service discription here: [web-service](https://www.bundesbank.de/en/statistics/time-series-databases/help-for-sdmx-web-service) and you can try it out here [Bundesbank SDMX](https://api.statistiken.bundesbank.de/doc/index.html?urls.primaryName=Deutsche%20REST%20API%20Dokumentation). You could also use htmlUnit to automatically download the csv-files but I would not recomend it.

Comment: @Eritrean, I am really grateful for your help. To be honest, this is my first time working with APIs , so I don't know even why I have missed this page in their websites :D
But anyway thank you for your help :)